# How to rebuild epoll package in electron?

Tags: javascript, raspberry-pi, node-gyp, epoll, electron-rebuild

I try to rebuild an electron app but I got this error regarding the epoll installation.

```
Building module: epoll, Completed: 0gyp: name 'openssl_fips' is not defined while evaluating condition 'openssl_fips != ""' in binding.gyp while trying to load binding.gyp
✖ Rebuild Failed
An unhandled error occurred inside electron-rebuild
node-gyp failed to rebuild '/home/pi/ma-0042-cihaz-be/node_modules/epoll'.
For more information, rerun with the DEBUG environment variable set to "electron-rebuild".
Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
Error: node-gyp failed to rebuild '/home/pi/ma-0042-cihaz-be/node_modules/epoll'.
For more information, rerun with the DEBUG environment variable set to "electron-rebuild".
at NodeGyp.rebuildModule (/home/pi/ma-0042-cihaz-be/node_modules/electron-rebuild/lib/src/module-type/node-gyp.js:109:19)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async ModuleRebuilder.rebuildNodeGypModule (/home/pi/ma-0042-cihaz-be/node_modules/electron-rebuild/lib/src/module-rebuilder.js:94:9)
    at async Rebuilder.rebuildModuleAt (/home/pi/ma-0042-cihaz-be/node_modules/electron-rebuild/lib/src/rebuild.js:226:9)
    at async Rebuilder.rebuild (/home/pi/ma-0042-cihaz-be/node_modules/electron-rebuild/lib/src/rebuild.js:184:17)
    at async /home/pi/ma-0042-cihaz-be/node_modules/electron-rebuild/lib/src/cli.js:154:9
```

I am using a raspberry, I did update it too. But it didn't work.
These are the dependencies installed.

```
{
 
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "history": "^5.1.0",
    "i2c-bus": "^5.2.2",
    "jest": "^27.3.1",
    "jest-fetch-mock": "^3.0.3",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mfrc522-rpi": "^2.1.3",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "network-config": "^3.0.0",
    "node-cron": "^3.0.0",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.5",
    "node-wifi": "^2.0.15",
    "pi-camera": "^1.6.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.0.0",
    "realm": "^10.7.0",
    "rpi-gpio": "^2.1.7",
    "rpi-softspi": "^1.0.5",
    "rpio": "^2.4.2",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.16"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.5",
    "@babel/node": "^7.15.4",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.16.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.6",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "electron": "8.2.0",
    "electron-builder": "^22.11.7",
    "electron-rebuild": "^3.2.3",
    "electron-webpack": "^2.8.2",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.6",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.6.2",
    "webpack": "~4.42.1"
  }
}
```

I deleted node_modules with package-lock.json and installed everything again. I updated the raspberry with apt-get upgrade. I don't know how can I solve this issue. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `gyp: name 'openssl_fips' is not defined while evaluating condition 'openssl_fips != ""' in binding.gyp while trying to load binding.gyp`

I just spent my day solving this. Eventually, here's what has worked for me.

- install the latest `node-gyp` locally:

  ```
  npm install -d node-gyp@latest
  ```
- in `binding.gyp`, add (at the top):

  ```
  {
      "variables": {
          "openssl_fips" : "0" 
      },

      ...      
  }
  ```

Comment: I have this issue with NodeJS 17. Can you please tell where exactly (which binding.gyp) the code above must be added? I tried to add it as described in the binding.gyp of the module that fails, but unfortunately it doesn't help. Thanks!

Comment: @Bernd, I was having this problem with Electron, can't speak of Node. I put that at the very top `binding.gyp`. You already should have the root opining `{` and closing `}` brackets there.

Comment: Hacky: For __build failures in external packages__ (gotten from `npm install`), I went into the `node_modules` and access the `binding.gyp` of the faultypackage at fault to append the openssl_fips as shared above. I am remove the `build` directory in the package directory. Doing `npm install` again after the change will be successful.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, after updating NodeJS to version 17.0.1, the same problems started.

The whole problem was in the **bcrypt** package, it no longer meets the standards of version 17

In my case, reduced the version to 16 helped.

Comment: This helped me, electron-builder was giving `npm ERR! command sh -c node-gyp rebuild` on nodejs 17, but 16 works.

Answer (score 3):

electron-rebuild v3.2.5 released.

The problem was solved after updating!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I have a same problem too, but i am using a serialport not epoll.

So, I think the cause of this problem is electron modules not the native module.

```js
yarn run v1.22.15
$ electron-rebuild -f -w myapp
\ Building module: bindings, Completed: 0gyp: name 'openssl_fips' is not defined while evaluating condition 'openssl_fips != ""' in binding.gyp while trying to load binding.gyp
× Rebuild Failed

An unhandled error occurred inside electron-rebuild
node-gyp failed to rebuild 'C:\Users\node_modules\@serialport\bindings'.
For more information, rerun with the DEBUG environment variable set to "electron-rebuild".

Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1



Error: node-gyp failed to rebuild 'C:\Users\node_modules\@serialport\bindings'.
For more information, rerun with the DEBUG environment variable set to "electron-rebuild".

Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1


    at NodeGyp.rebuildModule (C:\Users\node_modules\electron-rebuild\lib\src\module-type\node-gyp.js:109:19)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async ModuleRebuilder.rebuildNodeGypModule (C:\Users\node_modules\electron-rebuild\lib\src\module-rebuilder.js:94:9)
    at async Rebuilder.rebuildModuleAt (C:\Users\node_modules\electron-rebuild\lib\src\rebuild.js:226:9)
    at async Rebuilder.rebuild (C:\Users\node_modules\electron-rebuild\lib\src\rebuild.js:184:17)
    at async C:\Users\node_modules\electron-rebuild\lib\src\cli.js:154:9
error Command failed with exit code 4294967295.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

This problem started yesterday. There were no problems in the last week.

I already installed the windows-build-tools, node-gyp, python 3.x.

I set the npm config & yarn config & python Env path, msvs_version too.

I reinstalled above packages many many times but not work electron-rebuild.

That is whole Error messages. There is no more Error messages.

What should we do?

Comment: [The answear above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69896681/16638833) seemed to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I use a PowerShell script based on @noseratio's answer.

```
    $path = ".\node_modules\@nodert-win10-rs4\windows.devices.geolocation\binding.gyp"

    $content = Get-Content $path
    $content = $content -replace '"USE_ADDITIONAL_WINMD": "true"', '"USE_ADDITIONAL_WINMD": "true", "openssl_fips": ""'
    $content | Set-Content $path -Encoding Ascii
```